# I can't install libsodium on code blocks for a C program

Tags: c, download, codeblocks, libsodium

I'm new to programming and I can't install the libsodium library to make a program in C on code blocks, is this possible? If so, can you help me? thank you very much.

I've looked at quite a few forums and tried a lot of things, particularly in the code blocks build option. I don't really understand how to go about it and I don't see how I could solve this problem as a novice in programming.

Comment: Your question seems borderline off-topic on this site, but might be more on-topic on another Stack Exchange website. You should at least specify which OS / CPU you are using.